# Javafx 2 dimensional TabPane

Tags: java, javafx, tabpanel

Is it possible to make a 2 dimensional TabPane in Javafx (You know where 1 line of tabs looks to be behind another line of tabs?)

And if so how? ive been looking around but all i could find about TabPanes are Css related (styling)

**Updat - Picture of tabs made in swing**

[image: Swing way of tabPane]

Comment: Can you give an image what you are mentioning?

Comment: @UlukBiy - Updated my post showing an image with a swing example

Comment: @UlukBiy Do you know how i would be able to accomplish it?

Comment: Sorry currently I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for a solution, too.

My first idea, i am using a fxml file with a vbox.
The vbox contains two instances of a TabPane.

My controller has a tab counter "index". When I add a tab, then I increment the
tab counter. The first 5 tabs will be added into the first tabPane and then the tabs will be added into the second tabPane below.

It sounds like a workaround, but may be it is a solution.

```
    if (index <= 5){
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("tab number: " + index.toString()));
    }
    else {
        tabPane2.getTabs().add(new Tab("tab number: " + index.toString()));
    }

    index++;
```